# Full youtube background video

Tags: html, video, youtube, background

I'm trying to build a landing page with a full youtube video background. I've got this [piece of code](https://codepen.io/mattgrosswork/pen/jrdwK) on CodePen and as you can see by clicking on it, it works perfectly.

```
<article>
  <h1>GROSS DESIGN co. <br /> <span>(Made by <a href="http://mattgross.io" target="_blank">Matt Gross</a>, for <a href="https://evenvision.com">EvenVision</a>)</span></h1>
</article>

<!--  Video is muted & autoplays, placed after major DOM elements for performance & has an image fallback  -->
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But when I change the source to a youtube link (specifically [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyIJoCI2p40)), it does not work. Could anyone, please, explain me what is wrong and how to fix it? I'd appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: Please edit your tags relevant to your programming language.

Comment: You need to provide an actual video file (like `somevideo.mp4`). Your Vimeo link gives an MP4 video file link that's why it works, but Youtube links are for a web page. You'll just have to pre-download the Youtube video first (use some Youtube saver site) then upload that file onto your site.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One. I did that and it worked